# How to implement the slider card in Carosol 3 using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, owl-carousel

Note: I am not promoting the products listed on the screenshot as it is not functional yet.

I am making a *Woocomerence+Worpress* site theme to my customer and i code it with pinegrow editor. 
I have tree owls carousel slider in main page and its front-page.

**Carousel 1** purpose = Show customer latest product, what are added. *Left to right*
**Carousel 2** purpose = Show customer most highest rated product. *Left to right*
**Carousel 3** purpose = Show customer products that are on sale. *Left to right*

**Problem** =  my php.code works but don't go to right cards in slider, Do I need own codes for each card?, or is there better way to do it? and how I can change code to make Carousel 2 and 3 work like it 
description.

[image: screenshot to problem]

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <?php
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'stock' => 1,
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'orderby' =>'date',
'order' => 'DESC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
    <div class="span3">
        <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="My Image Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4><span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span></a>
        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#reviews"> Arvosteluja: <?php echo $product->get_review_count(); ?> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /span3 -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I have made a few modifications to the question. Are you trying to implement the slider card in Carosol 3? To improve your question, can you please provide a live link to the mock-advertisement website?

Comment: Hi, Its just exsample, my customer sell toys but not in online and pictures are not his toys.

Comment: Im running local host with program. Proplem is when i run php code carousel 1 its stack items to vertical line and i want all items horisontal line, inside cards. Sory my bad english..